Upgraded to cudnn 9.1.1, but Python only recognizes 8.5.0
I work on Jupyter Lab, managed by PyCharm. I've recently upgraded my cuda to 12.4:
which nvcc
yields:
/usr/local/cuda-12.4/bin/nvcc
I've also upgraded cudnn to 9.1.1, using the x86_64 ubuntu 2204 local deb installation method from
https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn-downloads
Unfortunately when I try (in an .ipynb notebook under Jupyter Lab):
import torch
cudnn_version = torch.backends.cudnn.version()
print("CuDNN version:", cudnn_version)

I get:
CuDNN version: 8500 
Additional information:
Software & Updates indicates GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-550 (proprietary)
Has anyone any suggestions to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

The official Pytorch builds ship with the required GPU runtime components it requires. It doesn't use an external CUDA toolkit or associated libraries unless you do something deliberate which usually breaks Pytorch.

Thank you for the answer. I've updated both tensorflow and pytorch; both show CuDNN version: 8500. So does this error:
E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:458] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 8.5.0 but source was compiled with: 8.9.6.  CuDNN library needs to have matching major version and equal or higher minor version. If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime is compatible with the version specified during compile configuration.
mean I just can't use the downloaded model on a local machine?

Uninstalling both Tensorflow and Pytorch, rebooting and reinstalling them (through Pycharm) did the trick.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
